# SSH: What does this delay mean?

Tags: ssh

I'm getting a delay of 10-15 seconds when SSHing into a remote server.The `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` has the following options and nothing else.

```
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

Here is the debug outputs with `-vvv` option.

```
...
expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
set_newkeys: mode 0
SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
Roaming not allowed by server
SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
service_accept: ssh-userauth
SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa (0x0),
key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0),

---> DELAY HERE <---

Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
start over, passed a different list publickey,password
preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
authmethod_lookup publickey
remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
...
```

I've seen posts where people suggest setting `UseDNS no` and/or `GSSAPIAuthentication no`, but this seems like it's looking for a key from the logs. I've tried to force using a passowrd (`-o PubkeyAuthentication=no`) with no success.

Any idea?

Comment: Why not just try it?

Comment: I like to research things like that before trying them out and didn't want to interfere with anybody else's work. I thought, perhaps, it had something to do with the server looking for a key on my machine from looking at the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still could be a DNS issue. Using UseDNS on the client side won't affect what the server does, and if it has UseDNS yes in sshd_config or uses TCP Wrappers it could be looking up your name and re-resolving what IP that name corresponds to.